# Flash FileReference.upload() doesn't call url

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, upload

After moving a web site to another server flash upload stopped working. After some debuging and isolating the problem I found out that in SWF file (used for multiple upload) **FileReference.upload()** method doesn't work. URL called by item.upload(_root.uploadScript) isn't called.

Here is the code:

flash:

```
listener.onSelect = function(fileRefList:FileReferenceList){
  var list:Array = fileRefList.fileList;
  var item:FileReference;
  _root.toUploadCount = list.length;
  for(var i:Number = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    item = list[i];
    if(item.size > maxSize)
      ExternalInterface.call("tooBig", item.name);
    else{           
      item.addListener(this);
      item.upload(_root.uploadScript);
    }
  }
}
```

upload.php:

```
<?php

$log = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($log, 'Upload');
fclose($log);
```

item.upload(_root.uploadScript) returns true, but log file isn't created.

CHMOD is set correctly, direct call of upload.php creates log.txt as expected and everything worked on the previous server.

Please help, I'm clueless.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the swf loaded from the same domain (including sub domain) as upload.php is on? I'm thinking it could possibly be a same origin/cross domain security issue, if the move also included some changes in how the files are served with regards to domains used.

Comment: Lars Blåsjö: Thanks for response. Yes, both SWF and upload.php are on the same domain. _root.uploadScript is relative path. I also tried it to be absolute. No effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Server was returning **HTTP Error 406**. To prevent this behavior I needed to add to **.htaccess** file this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Content-Type "^multipart/form-data;" "MODSEC_NOPOSTBUFFERING=Do not buffer file uploads"
```